# UISlider not updating to bound ViewModel Property

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got a UISeekbar and a UILabel located inside an MvxView

```
        _currentPositionText = new UILabel { TextColor = UIColor.White };
        _seekBar = new UISlider
            {
                MinValue = 0,
                Continuous = true,
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
            };
        _seekBar.TouchDown += OnTouchDown;
        _seekBar.TouchUpInside += OnTouchUpInside;
        _seekBar.TouchDragInside += OnDragInside;
```

I'm setting the binds as follows

```
        set.Bind(_seekBar).For(sb => sb.Value).To(vm => _viewModel.CurrentPositionMsec);
        set.Bind(_seekBar).For(sb => sb.MaxValue).To(vm => _viewModel.DurationMsec);
        set.Bind(_currentPositionText).To(vm => vm.CurrentPositionText);
```

If I add some trace code inside the `get` of the `CurrentPositionMsec`, I can see the property updating once per second (as expected).

*note: That same method also updates the `CurrentPositionText` by simply formatting the milliseconds into a TimeSpan.*

The binding for the `_currentPositionText` is updating as expected, but the `_seekBar` doesn't update the slider position.

**The expected result is for the slider to update once per second based on the `CurrentPositionMsec`.**

I have this working in Android with the following binding, and both Android and iOS are sharing the same viewModel.

```
<SeekBar
    android:Foo=""
    android:Bar=""
    local:MvxBind="Max DurationMsec; Progress CurrentPositionMsec" />
```

Am I not setting something up right? This "should" work AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reordering the bindings does not appear to yield any better results

```
// binding MaxValue first doesn't fix (lambda)
set.Bind(_seekBar).For(sb => sb.MaxValue).To(vm => _viewModel.DurationMsec);
set.Bind(_seekBar).For(sb => sb.Value).To(vm => _viewModel.CurrentPositionMsec);
```

Changing the binding to use a string rather than a lambda DID prove to solve the issue.

```
// using a string did enable the bindings to work as expected.
set.Bind(_seekBar).For("MaxValue").To(vm => _viewModel.DurationMsec);
set.Bind(_seekBar).For("Value").To(vm => _viewModel.CurrentPositionMsec);
```

We have now chosen to use strings as a standard in our code base. It does leave room for mistakes since we don't get compile time errors, but at least it ensures the bindings work.

Answer (score 0):

I added a second SeekBar to the `SeekView` sample in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples

This code seemed to work well:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 100, 100, 30));
        label.Text = "Slide me:";
        Add(label);
        var seek = new UISlider(new RectangleF(110, 100, 200, 30));
        seek.MinValue = 0;
        seek.MaxValue = 100;
        Add(seek);
        var seek2 = new UISlider(new RectangleF(110, 160, 200, 30));
        seek2.MinValue = 0;
        seek2.MaxValue = 100;
        Add(seek2);
        var mirrorLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(110, 130, 200, 30));
        mirrorLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Blue;
        Add(mirrorLabel);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SeekView, SeekViewModel>();
        set.Bind(seek).To(vm => vm.SeekProperty);
        set.Bind(seek2).To(vm => vm.SeekProperty);
        set.Bind(mirrorLabel).To(vm => vm.SeekProperty);
        set.Apply();
    }
```

[image: simulator image]

Obviously this only exercises the current value and **not** the maximum - but hopefully getting this working will help.

---

My only suggestion might be to try reordering your bindings - so that MaxValue is set before Value is. Or perhaps try using a fixed MaxValue and then using a value converter (or other mechanism) to scale the current value.